# Python hashing folder contents results in memory error

Tags: python, windows, cryptography, robotframework, md5

**Context**

In an automated test case I download a folder containing

- txt files, and
- encrypted files with various 3 digit extensions(i.e. .001, .004)

and hash every one of these files in the following manner:

```
def hash_directory(path):
    hashed_files = {}
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                buf = f.read(65536)
                if not buf : break
                md5.update(buf)
        return {os.path.basename(path):md5.hexdigest()}
    else:
        for dir_name, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
            for filename in file_names:

                md5 = hashlib.md5()
                file_path = os.path.join(dir_name.replace(path, '').strip('\\'),filename)
                with open(os.path.join(dir_name, filename), 'rb') as f:
                    part = 0
                    while True:
                        buf = f.read(65536)
                        if not buf: break
                        md5.update(buf)
                        #if the md5 object gets larger than a quarter MB, then digest a part of the file.
                        if sys.getsizeof(md5)>262144:
                            hashed_files[file_path+'part'+str(part)] = md5.hexdigest()
                            part+=1
                    hashed_files[file_path] = md5.hexdigest()
        return hashed_files
```

I do the same for a folder being held on a server on my network(this is the "expected"), and compare the `hashed_files` to determine if there are missing files in the downloaded folder, or if any files are corrupted.

**Problem**

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 550, in <module>
    run_cli(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 489, in run_cli
    return RobotFramework().execute_cli(arguments, exit=exit)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 46, in execute_cli
    rc = self._execute(arguments, options)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 90, in _execute
    error, details = get_error_details(exclude_robot_traces=False)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\error.py", line 47, in get_error_details
    details = ErrorDetails(exclude_robot_traces=exclude_robot_traces)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\error.py", line 60, in ErrorDetails
    raise exc_value
MemoryError
```

We use robot framework for writing the test cases, python27, and this occurs both on my win10 16gb machine, and on remote servers running the code.

Would anyone have a sniff of what this could be ?
Does anyone know of a python tool to monitor memory as code is run ?

Comment: So, which line/lines are the errors related to?

Comment: How many files are there? Can you run this code without using the framework? It completely strips the error message of all context, making it pretty useless. Also, the `md5` object can't get larger than a quarter MB. Its internal state has a fixed size.

Comment: Finally, why don't you just use `rsync`? It's extremely fast, designed specifically for transferring large numbers of files between servers, and implements checksums.